# Django login not working. Only works for superuser/admin

Tags: python, django

I was using django-registration-redux for my registration backend earlier and everything worked fine. I then decided to change the registration backend to django's default registration `django.contrib.auth` and the registration has been working fine but the login doesn't work. However, the thing is, only my superuser acoount can login, every other user can't login, both the regular users and the ones with staff clearance. It keeps giving me invalid username/password error.

Below is the login section of my views.py

```
def signin(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
form = LoginForm()
errors = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        username = username.lower()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if user.is_staff:
            return redirect('sweet:vendor_index')
        else:
            return redirect('sweet:index')
    else:
        errors = "Invalid Username or Password"
return render(request, 'myregistration/signin.html', {'form':form, 'errors':errors})
```

Below is my signin.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}sign in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Sign in</h1>

{% if form.errors %}
<p class="error">Please correct the errors below:</p>
  {{ errors }}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'myregistration:signin' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<dl>
<dt><label for="id_username">Username:</label>{% if form.username.errors %} <span class="error">{{ form.username.errors|join:", " }}</span>{% endif %}</dt>
<dd>{{ form.username }}</dd>
<dt><label for="id_password">Password:</label>{% if form.password.errors %} <span class="error">{{ form.password.errors|join:", " }}</span>{% endif %}</dt>
<dd>{{ form.password }}</dd>
<dt><input type="submit" value="sign in" /></dt>
</dl>
</form>
<p>Forgotten password? Click <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">here</a> to reset password</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block content-related %}
<p>If you don't have an account, you can <a href="/accounts/register/">sign
up</a> for one.
{% endblock %}
```

And finally, my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myregistration import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views    

app_name = 'myregistration'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register_vendor/', views.register_vendor, name='register_vendor'),
    url(r'^register_customer/', views.register_customer, name='register_customer'),
    url(r'^email_confirm/', views.email_confirm, name='email_confirm'),
    url(r'^password_change/$', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

Below is my registration method

```
def register_customer(request):
registered = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    customerform = CustomerSignUpForm(data=request.POST)

    if customerform.is_valid():
        customer = customerform.save(commit=False)
        # Remeber to hash password again
        customer.set_password(customer.password)
        customer.is_active = False
        customer.is_staff = False
        customer.save()

        text_content = "Account Activation Email"
        mail_subject = "Activate your Juggernut account"
        template_name = "myregistration/account_activate.html"
        from_email = customerform.cleaned_data.get('email')
        recipients = [customer.email]
        kwargs = {
            "uidb64":urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(customer.pk)).decode(),
            "token":account_activation_token.make_token(customer)
        }
        activation_url = reverse("myregistration:activate", kwargs=kwargs)
        activation_url = "{0}://{1}{2}".format(request.scheme, request.get_host(), activation_url)

        context = {
            'customer':customer, 
            'activation_url':activation_url
        }
        html_content = render_to_string(template_name, context)
        email=EmailMultiAlternatives(mail_subject, text_content, from_email, recipients)
        email.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
        email.send()
        return redirect("myregistration:email_confirm")
        registered=True
    else:
        print(customerform.errors)

else:
    customerform = CustomerSignUpForm()
return render(request, 'myregistration/register_customer.html', {'customerform':customerform, 'registered':registered})
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: How do you create users?

Comment: @AaronGarton It keeps telling me invalid username or password

Comment: @neverwalkaloner By registering them. I'll add the registration view now

Comment: I would suggest using the framework's default `User` model. If you need to customize the model, pass new parameters as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, in your views you have a form class to your view `form = LoginForm()`, but in your template you're not rendering this form and you won't be able to validate it and the line `if form.is_valid():` will always return False.

You have two options, render the form class or change:

```
form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        username = username.lower()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if user.is_staff:
            return redirect('sweet:vendor_index')
        else:
            return redirect('sweet:index')
    else:
        errors = "Invalid Username or Password"
```

to:

```
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        username = username.lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.is_staff:
                return redirect('sweet:vendor_index')
        else:
            return redirect('sweet:index')
```

Probably the LoginForm class take another parameters and cannot be validated

Comment: Removing the if form.is_valid validators return `AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error`

Comment: @Gozie you have to check if authenticate method worked check this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: @Maurcio Cortazar It doesn't produce an error anymore however, it redirects me to index page without actually logging me in

Comment: @Gozie then your credentials are incorrect or your user doesn't exist, try using authenticate method from the shell, and see if return a user

Comment: @Gozie also make sure this line doesn't affect your login `username = username.lower()`

Comment: You didn't put an else for if `user.is_staff`, so where is it meant to direct non-staff users to?

Comment: You should check if user isn't staff before login it

Comment: But I want to use the same view to log in staff and non staff, where then would be the wise place to put the staff condition check?

Comment: It hasn't. Didn't you see my latest comment?

Comment: It returns None even when the user details are correct

Comment: which form i need to use with login view. right now i m using `AuthenticationForm` but `form.is_valid` always return false. i don't know why that shit happing